# Raster Band Calculations in C# using gdal_calc

Tags: c#, image-processing, raster, gdal

I have two raster files in JP2 format.  I need to combine the two and perform a calculation against the bands.  Is there any way to do this in .NET and C#?  Most references I see to performing this use Gdal's calc function in python.

I have tried utilizing the Gdal.Core and Gdal.Core.WindowsRuntime, but I don't see any wrappers for the Calculate call.  Has anyone attempted to do this before, and, if so, how did you manage to make the call, or what library did you use?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm sure someone has made the attempt.  Statistically speaking, the chances of at least one other developer trying it are probably fairly significant.  But that's not really your question, is it?

Comment: More like, how did they make the call?  I'll add some clarification.

Comment: Have a look here: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that, but nowhere does it mention anything about the gdal_calc method being implemented.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you need to do it manually as far as I know, you have to open both Datasets, get the bands that you need, make the calculations on them, and then Create a new output file, writing each of the new data to a different band.

There are some examples in the GDAL/OGR In CSharp page here:

https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/csharp/apps

For rasters you'll need to read carefully GDALReadDirect.cs and GDALDatasetRasterIO.cs

If you really see that what you want to do has a simpler solution in Python I would do that instead.

[GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) is a good place to ask questions on these topics.

Comment: I have no problem running the python, but it's been a real pain getting the gdal package on Windows that includes the gdal_calc.py piece that is needed.  Assuming I get that, I could use one of the python wrappers to execute that script from the c# environment, right?

Comment: If you have QGIS installed you already have gdal_calc, you can try running it from your OSGeo4W64 folder, it's usually on `C:` or `C:\Program Files`, inside that folder search for `OSGeo4W.bat` and you can test it from any terminal using that route with the next command `.\OSGeo4W.bat gdal_calc -help` (you just don't use -help when doing the calculations).

Comment: Or just use the OSGeo4W Shell, it should be in your installed programs, you can search for it from the Windows Home Menu. After opening the shell you can just `gdal_calc -help`